# Use of '?' during casting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, casting

I have a sample piece of code with me:

```
bool _HasParsed;
object IsCheckedAsObj = GetCheckedStatus();
if (IsCheckedAsObj == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Status not found");
}
_HasParsed = (bool?)IsCheckedAsObj;    //why (bool?) instead of (bool)
```

In the last line, I can understand that they are parsing the object to boolean. But what is that '?' doing there? Whats the difference between (bool?) instead of (bool)?

Comment: Does this sample piece of code compile? I didn't think you could assign a `Nullable<bool>` to a `bool`.

Comment: yep....it did not...but I got the information for using Nullable values. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `bool?` is shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`.

The code doesn't compile as it stands. You will get the error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.".

If you declare the variable as nullable too, it will work:

```
bool? _HasParsed;
```

That might of course mean that you need to do other changes in the code. You can use `_HasParsed.HasValue` to check if the variable is not null, and use `_HasParsed.Value` to get the bool value.

Comment: so what will be the result, if casting fails?

Comment: @rapsalands I believe, if `IsCheckedAsObj` is either `null`, a `bool` or a `Nullable<bool>` (`bool?`) it will work. If `IsCheckAsObj` is none of these, casting will fail and an exception thrown. If this is undesired, try `_HasParsed = IsCheckedAsObj as bool?;`

Comment: @rapsalands: If the casting fails, you will get the exception `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer. SO asking me to accept the answer only after more 6 minutes

Answer (score 4):

`bool?` is shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`. Your code doesn't need it though, because there's a check against `null` before the assignment.

**Edited:** As Jeow Li Huan correctly stated in the comments, the check for `null` implies that the return value of `GetCheckedStatus()` is of type `bool?`. The following simplified snipped will do the same as the original code in OP's question:

```
object IsCheckedAsObj = GetCheckedStatus();
if (IsCheckedAsObj == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Status not found");
bool _HasParsed = (bool)IsCheckedAsObj;
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know you could directly cast a `bool?` to `bool`.  Thought you had to use `.Value`  (obviously fails if it's null at runtime, but I thought it would be compile error).  I just checked it and it does work though.

Comment: Your edited version is less correct. If GetCheckedStatus() returns bool, if (IsCheckedAsObj == null) will always be false. So we should assume it returns bool?. The same code works and does not need calls to HasValue or Value

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `bool` and `bool?` is that `bool?` is a `Nullable<bool>` which means that the bool has three possible values: `false`, `true` and `null` (= not set).

```
bool? nullableBool = null;

if ( b.HasValue )
{
   bool notNullableBool = b.Value;
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s) is the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Except that you need to call `.Value` to get the actual `bool` value.  I'm sure you knew that, but it wasn't expressed in the answer.

Comment: Thnx. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Types with `?`, such as `bool?` are [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). Learn how to [use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It also can be represented as `Nullable<bool>`. And can only be applied for `struct` types.

Nullable type's feature is that you can assign its value or `null` to them. 


Using:

```
int? number;
// do something with number
if (number.HasValue)
{
  Console.WriteLine(number.Value);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No value");
}
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(number.HasValue ? number.Value : "No value");
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it's a `boolean` that can also be `null`.

See [Nullable Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is shorthand for the struct below:

```
struct Nullable<T> 
{ 
    public bool HasValue; 
    public T Value; 
}
```

You can use this struct directly, but the ? is the shortcut syntax to make the resulting code much cleaner. Rather than typing:
    Nullable x = new Nullable(125);

Instead, you can write:
    int? x = 125;

This doesn't work with string, as a string is a Reference type and not a Value type.